# how to setup and use W3C Web Speech API from a local html file?

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, webspeech-api

I want to make use of W3C Web Speech API, which already have a demo at https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/demos/speech.html.

I want to enhance it as a continuous speech recognition service and hopefully it can be run from a local html file on an android phone which can have features added to its currently demo. Now, I find that the local file cannot access the microphone when running in Chrome  or android webview.

I know little how to setup this API. For example, what files I need to install in order to make use of this API?

Also, does this recognition service needed to be paid?

Comment: How do you open a local html file on an android phone?

Comment: save a html file in the phone. click it and it opens in chrome.
 I also try some android app like http server or web server but it seems it open it as a file. I want a web server in the phone if needed and possible

Comment: You can either create an app or host this html file on github for free or use a local http server

Comment: if I setup  local http server in Window, do I just need the source code of the demo? Do I need to install additional files to run the recognition service? Firstly I need to successfully duplicate the demo.

Comment: what do you mean local http server? do you mean accessing it using localhost or one that do not need an fixed ip address ?